# how to make url rewrite apache whitout any rewrite condition?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

sorry, but i'am less understand about url rewrite...

i want to rewrite my url from :
`http://localhost/controller/index.php/user/edit`
to
`http://localhost/controller/user/edit`

i can make it with this .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /controller/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

but, the rewrite works if there is no file exist at `controller/user/edit.php`
i want every request to under my `controller/xxx` is rewrited to `controller/index.php/xxx` whether the file is exist or not....

i have remove the `RewriteCond` so my current one is like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /controller/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

but, it shown *`internal service error`*..

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that don't make sense to me.  Mainly, your question says to want to rewrite a URL having index.php in it to one that does not, but your rewrite rule, which you say works in some cases does the opposite, it pre-pends index.php to requests.

If you have access to your apache error and access log, you might see if there's more information about exactly at what point the error occurred -- was it when the .htaccess file was processed, or was it from within your php program?

I will assume that the goal here is to take "pretty" urls like /controller/user/edit and have the index.php program actually process the /user/edit part of the path.

If so, I think you may want to set the RewriteBase to /, and change your .htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller/index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

The `RewriteBase /` directive says that all requests are relative to the server's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` setting.  The change to the rewrite rule instructs all requests to go to the directory `controller` and file `index.php`, appending the original requested path afterwards.

(Note: I don't think you want to use the `PT` flag in this case, and it would be better form to escape the . which is a regex operator as `index\.php`, but I think neither of these are relevant to the problem here)

It is not clear if you do want the / before the $1.  If your PHP program (index.php) is getting called with it present, and knows how to handle it, then it's fine, but it's a little unusual, and there may be cases where you end up with multiple /'s from within the php program.

But do you really want to do this?  The typical use of the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is to handle cases such as image files and css or javascript files that are static and need not be handled by your controller. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` depends on your system (but it's purpose to see that the request is not for a directory).

Anyway, the basic change as I proposed might help, but if not, perhaps you can clarify your intent and provide some actual URLs and a look inside index.php